# command line: execute ASP.Net Core dll with certain profile name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Please help me to specify profile name when I'm running ASP.Net Core application using the `dotnet WebApplicationLaunchProfile.dll`

I use this short form just to have possibility to run the project outside of VS and check how it works.

I know that I can use `dotnet run --launch-profile testProfileName` however it requires `.csproj` and `.cs` source files to be available. I would like to avoid copying source code files and use compiled assemblies. My flow is:

- build with `dotnet build`
- copy build result (`bin\Debug` folder content) to the separate folder
- start the dll to use proper profile name using the `dotnet WebApplicationLaunchProfile.dll` form

However the problem is that

> When the app is launched with dotnet run, the first profile with "commandName": "Project" is used

rule [from the documentation is not applied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development) if project is executed with `dotnet dll` command. It is clear that it should not be applied since I'm not using the `dotnet run` command.

However I'd like to specify profile name somehow.

I've created new ASP.Net Core project from VS template and updated the `launchSettings.json` file as below:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
...
  "profiles": {
...
    "WebApplicationLaunchProfile": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:4430;http://localhost:8080",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've adjusted the `profiles:WebApplicationLaunchProfile:applicationUrl` value and replaced 5000 and 5001 ports as you can see.
Project was uploaded to the https://github.com/oleksabor/curly-broccoli just for quick reference.
But there were no modifications besides the `launchSettings.json`.

I can start the application using the VS or `dotnet run` command without any problem

However I'm getting error when executing the app with `dotnet dll` command like below:

```
C:\projects\WebApplicationLaunchProfile\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1>dotnet WebApplicationLaunchProfile.dll                                                     
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to start Kestrel.                                                                                                                   
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
```

I have port 5000 occupied and would like to use 4430 instead.

`dotnet WebApplicationLaunchProfile.dll --launch-profile WebApplicationLaunchProfile` does not work (error is the same)

Is it possible to set profile name with `dotnet dll` ?

Answer (score 4):

I would have thought `dotnet xxx.dll -launch-profile` would work. Did you use the default Program.cs file? (the one generated when we create a project from a template, with Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(...), this is where the configuration magic happens)

Otherwise, you can try setting this environment variable for your process: `ASPNETCORE_URLS`. It should be picked up and used. More information the github issue page [github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639). For example: `set ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:4430;http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: ASPNETCORE_URLS works but without double quotes, like `set ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://localhost:4430;http://localhost:8080`. However using profile name I can set not only urls but `environmentVariables` too so it would be nice to get profile applied

Comment: --launch-profile